# Java exception in 'NativeModules' java.lang.NoClassFoundError: com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredentials

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native

I am getting this error while running the app. I have everything setup for firebase auth and I am not using Phone Auth, so this error seems little weird.
This is my android/build.gradle file.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                name 'Google'
            }
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'    
        }    
    }
```

This is my android/app/build.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.plastinction"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':rn-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-pdf')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'

}
```

This is my Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.5.8",
    "native-base": "^2.7.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.1.3",
    "react-native-datepicker": "1.7.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "3.2.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "0.26.10",
    "react-native-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-pdf": "4.0.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.4",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  }
```

My build gets successful, but this error occures at app loading, Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by updating the firebase dependencies to latest version.
Just add this instead of your firebase dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
```